# PHP and MySQLi - Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a function which will check update and insert some data but I am having an issue in the first step where the $stmt->bind_param is saying that is not passing parameters by reference or something like that.

I have attached below the function code:

```
public function killTarget($killerid,$victimiid,$victimcode)
    {

        if ($this->checkUsercode($victimcode,$victimiid))
        {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE users SET status =? WHERE user_id =?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii",0,$victimiid);

            if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->fetch();

                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT victim_id FROM target WHERE killer_id = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("i",$victimiid);

                if ($stmt->execute())
                {
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($targetid);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO target (killer_id, victim_id) VALUES (?,?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ii",$killerid,$targetid);

                    if ($stmt->execute())
                    {
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->fetch();
                        $stmt->close();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Main::setMessage("targets.php",$this->_db->error,"alert-error");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the issue is happening in the first lines of the function here: $stmt->bind_param("ii",0,$victimiid);

Comment: I would recommend using the PDO object, in which case you could do `$stmt->execute(array(0, $victimiid));` instead of having to bind params with `bind_param`

Comment: Or something like that? Next time pay more attention to exact error messages and post them here when applicable. Those messages are there to help you, not just to annoy.

Answer (score 45):

You **cannot** do this in mysqli:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii",0,$victimiid);
```

The `0` needs to be a variable.

Try this:

```
$zero = 0;
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$zero,$victimiid);
```

Comment: I also want to add that global variables like define('global_string', 'test'); need to be converted as well.

Comment: Instead of creating a variable, it should be hard coded in the query itself. `$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE user_id =?");`

Answer (score 15):

Watch out! [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) accepts a **reference** to a variable, not a constant value. Therefore you have to create a variable to hold that `0` and then reference that variable instead.

```
$i = 0;
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $i, $victimiid);
```

Answer (score 11):

Make 0 a variable or include it directly in your query.

```
$zero = 0;
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $zero, $victimiid);
```